# SignalR hub Context.User.IsInRole(xyz) does not call CumstomRoleProvider

Tags: signalr, roleprovider

Within a signalR hub method, I'm trying to check if the user authenticated is within a specific role.  In plane MVC, I can call `user.IsInRole` and the class overriding `RoleProvider`'s `GetRolesForUser` method is called.

The CustomRoleProvider is set up in the web.config with:

```
    <roleManager cacheRolesInCookie="false" defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider" enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="CustomRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

When `user.IsInRole` is called `CustomRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(string username)` is called.

**Hub code**

```
  public IEnumerable<Items> GetList()
    {
        IList<Items> result;

        var user = Context.User;
        if (user.IsInRole("Test_Role"))
            result = itemProvider.GetItems();
        else
            result = new[] {  };

        return result;
    }
```

**CustomRoleProvider**

```
public class CustomRoleProvider:RoleProvider
{
     public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
     {
         return new[]{"Test_Role"};
     }
}
```

Why is this not working in signal R?  `user.IsInRole` does not call `GetRolesForUser` and always returns **False**.

Comment: You have Not provided an [MCVE] Please provide the code for your hubs where you are checking GetRoleForUser

Comment: @johnny5 More detail added.

Comment: Thanks +1 its alot more clear now